# Как выстроить адаптивную сетку из блоков на flexbox?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Есть контейнер в котором может быть много блоков, необходимо чтобы блоки были по 4 в ряд с фиксированным отступом между собой и в случае если их скажем 6 то оставшиеся 2 не расплывались на всю ширину контейнера или по разным сторонам. 
Пока что получилось сделать таким образом:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  min-width: 235px;
  max-width: 235px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Но такой вариант считаю неправильным так как здесь приходится устанавливать минимальную и максимальную ширину блоков которую впоследствии придется менять на разных разрешениях в зависимости от ширины контейнера, а так же если нужно будет изменить количество блоков в ряду на низших разрешениях то и мучатся с отступом справа.

Чувствую что есть реализация поинтереснее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сочетаем ширину в процентах с медийными запросами.
 Пробуйте этот пример в разных разрешениях экрана.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: silver;
  width: calc(25% - 5 * 2px);
  height: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 500px) {
  .container div {
    width: calc(50% - 3 * 2px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container div {
    width: calc(100% - 2 * 2px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на формулу расчёта ширины через calc, так как необходимо отнять межблочные отступы `margin:2px`.

Comment: Интересно, только я не до конца понял как вычитаются margin-ы. По формуле (25% - 5 * 2px) для чего в данном случае используется "- 5" и в дальнейшем это число меняется. Объясните по подробнее пожалуйста.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev потому что есть `margin 2px`, если уберём этот минус то общая ширина получится 25% *4 + пять раз по 2 пикселя на каждый margin, и в результате получется больше 100%, уже не четыре блока получится а три. Попробуйте убрать минусование и посмотрите что получится.

Comment: Значит если я правильно понял, почему вы используете именно цифру 5 в этой формуле, то это по количеству вот этих отступов http://prntscr.com/iinlwd. ?

Хотя я поигрался с этим значением и пока оно не достигло "1" блоков по прежнему оставалось 4.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev да, точно, по количеству отступов.

Comment: То что может работать и с меньшим минусованием, возможно из-за округления при делении на 4 (25%) в данном случае.

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение. Чтож, хоть я и искал немного другое решение, которое бы имело не круговой margin а только с одной стороны. Судя по всему такого решения нет.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev Если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его. По поводу `margin` поясните. Вы можете его и только с одной стороны определить, они же схлопываются...

Comment: Уже решил эту проблему, просто когда даю круговой margin по бокам блока родителя появлялся отступы которые делают уже конкретно этот блок на фоне других, решилось простым добавлением отрицательных margin-ов к блоку родителю.

Answer (score 0):

Простая сетка без media запросов

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
  <div class="block">6</div>
  <div class="block">7</div>
  <div class="block">8</div>
  <div class="block">9</div>
  <div class="block">10</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.block {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: calc(23% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```